# "Invalid Date" in node-soap response

Tags: xml, node.js, web-services, date, soap

In calling a SOAP service from node using node-soap, I am seeing issues with date formats. The date element in the soap response is showing up as "Invalid Date". Is there a way to have node-soap use a specific format string for the conversion?

For example:

```
client.addSoapHeader(wseeheader, "", "tns", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
client.FooService.FooServicePort.getTransactionDetail(args, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(result.getTransactionDetailReturn.transactionDate));
});
```

The value being logged is "Invalid Date", however the SOAP service appears to be returning "2016-02-16-05:00" in the xsd:date field.

Thanks in advance for any guidance!